# Setting cookies when CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to (*)

Tags: node.js, api, cookies, browser, cors

I'm building an API with Node.js and Express, with the intention that it will be accessed by users via API calls, as well as act as the RESTFUL back-end for my web application (React.js).

For this reason, I've set the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the wildcard (*), as it should be able to be accessed from external sources.

Currently, the API is running on localhost:8000, and the web-app is running on localhost:3000.

Now, I want to set a cookie when my `/login` endpoint is accessed. The cookie is not used for authentication, so I'm not worried about CSRF.

I'm setting the cookie like this:

```
res.cookie('token', 'value', {httpOnly:true});
```

The cookie gets set no problem when I use Postman, however when trying to access it with my webapp through the browser, the cookie does not get set.

After reading several posts on Stack Overflow, I understand that I need to set `credentials: include` when doing the fetch operation from my web application.

The problem is that this is not allowed on browsers, if `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to (*).

Is there any way to set the cookie on the browser under these conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/198714/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-doesnt-allow-sending-session-cookies See this answer on stackexchange for some reasoning behind this, but basically no, you cannot.

If you need an api with credentials, you should also know all of the possible sources that can get these credentials. Set the allow-origin to your localhost and or development server, and your eventual production address as outlined below.

I'm assuming you're using the `cors` package on your NodeJS server.

It should be configured to accept the cookies too. It would look something like this in the case of an Express Server.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials:true
}));
```

Additionally, as you correctly said, you would send the credentials along with any UI side calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my issue however is that I need my origin to be the wildcard (*), which is not allowed when credentials are set.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials see MDN for why you must specify an origin and cannot use wildcard when using with credentials

Answer (score 1):

I got around it by doing this (I am using the cors package from NPM):

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:true,
    credentials:true
}));
```

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

> origin: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header.
>   Possible values:
>
> ```
> Boolean - set origin to true to reflect the request origin, as defined by req.header('Origin'), or set it to false to disable CORS.
> ```

This makes it so that cors will essentially accept any origin based on the request header, while also allows the setting of cookies.